# How can I make a set of vertical names horizontal?

Tags: notepad

I have a vertical names such as:

`1- John
2- James
3- Mike
4- Tyrone
etc...`

I want to make them horizontal lined such as:
`1- John 2- James 3- Mike 4- Tyrone etc...`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can I know what exactly the problem? Can you expand the question?

Comment: Copy, the select a free cell and paste.special with transpose box checked.

Comment: Your tags is all over the place! Edit your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, I used notepad++ and used join lines C+J